# Can't login to MySQL DB with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I can login with my own user account which I added as an IAM user to the DB:

```
cloud_sql_proxy -enable_iam_login -instances=project:us-central1:myinstance=tcp:3306 -verbose
mysql -u "me" --host 127.0.0.1
```

But I cannot do this with a service account:

```
gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account mygsa@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
cloud_sql_proxy -enable_iam_login -instances=project:us-central1:myinstance=tcp:3306 -verbose
mysql -u "mygsa" --host 127.0.0.1
```

Using `set auth/impersonate_service_account` works for postgres DBs with IAM users, but MySQL throws this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mygsa'@'cloudsqlproxy~1.1.1.1' (using password: YES)
```

And looking on the Cloud SQL logs:

```
CloudSQL Instance's IAM access denied for user mygsa@project:us.iam.gserviceaccount.com: Error code :UNAUTHENTICATED Error Message :Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

mygsa is a `IAM (service account)` Cloud SQL  user.